# Prove that a function $G$ is continuous on $\mathbb R $\{$a$}

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, proof-writing

Here is the problem:

> Suppose that the function $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and that the function $G$ is equal to $F$ on $\mathbb R$\{$a$} for some fixed point $a \in \mathbb R$. Prove that
>
> a) $G$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$\{$a$}
>
> b) $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}G(x)$ exists and the value of this limit

Here is what I have done so far:

> **a)** For $G$ to be continuous $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}G(x) = G(b)$ for all points $b$ in the domain. Since $F(b)$ is continuous for all $b \in \mathbb R$, and $G(b) = F(b)$, where $b \not = a$, then $G(b)$ is continuous at all $b \in \mathbb R$ except when $b=a$. However, since the domain of $G$ is $\mathbb R$\{$a$}, $a$ is not in the domain of $G$. Thus, for all $b$ in the domain $\mathbb R$\{$a$}, $G(x) will be defined$, and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}G(x)$ will exists, with $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b}G(x)=G(b)$. Thus $G$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$\{$a$}.

Am I on the right track for **a**? And how do I even start **b**, I have no idea how to do that one.

Comment: For b), observe that $\lim_{x\to a}F(x)=F(a)$  - what does that say about $\lim_{x\to a}G(x)$?

Comment: it implies that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}G(x)=F(a)$ right? Would I show this using one sided limits? Or can i say since $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}F(x)=F(a)$, and $F(x) = G(x)$, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}G(x)=F(a)$?